# Getting an error in Xcode when integrating parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, parse-platform, xcode5

i am trying to integrate parse into my app in Xcode 5.0.2. The app builds just fine before parse is integrated into ApplDelegate.m. But when i put in the parse details and test code, i get 4 errors. here is what i put in:

```
[Parse setApplicationId:@"Redacted"
              clientKey:@"Redacted"];
[PFAnalytics trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions];

PFObject *testObject = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"TestObject"];
testObject[@"foo"] = @"bar";
[testObject saveInBackground];
```

and i get the following 4 errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
   (error 1) "_OBJC_CLASS_$_BFExecutor", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Parse(BFTask+Private.o)
      l_OBJC_$_CATEGORY_BFExecutor_$_Background in Parse(BFTask+Private.o)
  (error 2) "_OBJC_CLASS_$_BFTask", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFObject.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFFile.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFNetworkCommandRunner.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFQuery.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFRetryingCommandRunner.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFTaskQueue.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFUser.o)
      ...
  (error 3) "_OBJC_CLASS_$_BFTaskCompletionSource", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFObject.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFCommandCache.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFNetworkCommandRunner.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFTaskHTTPRequestOperation.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(BFTask+Private.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) (error 4)
```

Comment: You may want to regenerate your app keys since you have exposed them here

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you need to compile [the BoltsFramework](https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-iOS) for your simulator builds.

If it's not included in Parse already, you can download it from GitHub.  Then make sure the Project settings for it include "i386" for architectures, which would work for the simulator.

Comment: Michael, I see that I do have the bolts.framework with the parse sdk download. But how exactly do I integrate it and make sure i386 is included?

Comment: Is Bolts.framework something that's built (a subproject of your project) or something that's included?

Comment: i believe it is included not built in. I'm not sure though